# Flutter - make scrollable a page that contains a DefaultTabController

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing an app and I have a page in which I show a block of data and below that I show the tabBars and TabBarView containing additional data. The problem I am struggling with is that if I try to wrap the widget "DefaultTabController" with "SingleChildScrollView" it throws an error and the page does not work.

I need to find a way to show the tabBars and TabBarView at the bottom of the page and make the entire page scrollable

I put the code:

In the build method I put 4 widgets inside the column

- _showEventHeader shows a single image with a title
- _showUserAndEventData shows plain text
- _showTabs shows the tab headers
- _showTabsContent shows the content of the tabs (images and comments)

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            body: Column(
              children: [
                ..._showEventHeader(),
                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: _showUserAndEventData()),
                _showTabs(),
                _showTabsContent(),
              ],
            )

                
            ));
  }
  
  
  List<Widget> _showEventHeader() {
    return [
      SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          if (Val.valStr(widget.evento.bannerUrl).isNotEmpty) {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) {
              return FlypperFullImage(
                imgURL: widget.evento.bannerUrl,
              );
            }));
          }
        },
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          children: [
            FlypperCustomImageNetWork(
              imageURL: widget.evento.bannerUrl,
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              showAsRectangle: true,
              fillWidth: true,
            ),
            Container(
              child: FlypperQrImage(
                qrData: widget.evento.code,
                size: 65,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      !_ticketsAvailable
          ? Text('$_noTicketAvailableMessage',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2)
          : SizedBox(
              height: 1,
            ),
      Card(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        elevation: 5,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Text(
              Val.valStr(widget.evento.name).isNotEmpty
                  ? Val.valStr(widget.evento.name)
                  : 'Sin nombre',
              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .headline1 /*FlypperStyleHelper.eventTitle(context)*/),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 10,
      ),
    ];
  }
  
  
  
  Widget _showUserAndEventData() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: [
              this.user != null
                  ? /*FlypperCustomImageBase64(
                            imageBase64: this.user.profileImageUrl)*/
                  FlypperCustomImageNetWork(
                      imageURL: this.user.profileImageUrl,
                      keepImageCached: true,
                      height: 65,
                      width: 65,
                    )
                  : SizedBox(height: 1),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      this.user != null
                          ? this.user.userName.isEmpty
                              ? this.user.email
                              : this.user.userName
                          : '',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
                      /* FlypperStyleHelper.eventUserData(context, 18),*/
                    ),
                    Text(
                        this.user != null
                            ? Val.valInt(this.user.followers).toString() +
                                ' seguidores'
                            : '',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1
                        /*FlypperStyleHelper.eventUserData(context, 15),*/
                        )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ]),
            _getEventDetailInfo(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            _showBuyButton(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            FlypperIconButton(
              icon: Icons.location_on,
              width: 150,
              handlerFunction: () => _openMapWithCalculatedRoute(context),
            ),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.grey,
              thickness: 2,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  Widget _showTabs() {
    return TabBar(
      isScrollable: true,
      labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
      tabs: [
        Tab(
          text: 'Fotos, videos...',
          /*icon: Icon(Icons.event, color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor)*/
        ),
        Tab(
          text: 'Comentarios',
          /*icon: Icon(Icons.attach_file, color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor),*/
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _showTabsContent() {
    return Flexible(
      child: TabBarView(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  child: Column(children: [_getDetailImage()]),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(child: Text('Comments section')) //comentarios, pendiente

          // SingleChildScrollView(
          //   child: Container(
          //     color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          //     child: Column(children: [_getDetailImage()]),
          //   ),
          // ),
          // Container(child: Text('Comments section')) //comentarios, pendiente
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I also attached an screenshot so you can understand better what I am saying

Comment: here is the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTUb1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try this i have a give example and edit it some value :-

TabBar(

isScrollable: true,

unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),

indicatorColor: Colors.white,

```
tabs: [

       Tab(

       child: Text('Tab 1'),

       ),

       Tab(

       child: Text('Investment'),

       ),

       Tab(

       child: Text('Your Earning'),

       ),
```

]),

And all Widget vale call in a List view  Like this:-

_showEventHeader() {

return new Container(

```
  height: 20,

  child: ListView(

    shrinkWrap: true,

    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,

      Column(

        children: [])));}
```

Comment: I managed to fix it by using Slivers, I didn't know there were those awesome widgets, thank you anyway for your answer